# Cycles in a graph with $\delta \geqslant 3 $

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Imagine that $G$ is a graph that $\delta(G) \geqslant 3 $;

prove that $G$ has a cycle with length divisible by 3.

I may also add that the question consists of two parts, first prove that $G$ has a round with length NOT divisible by 3. this can be easily shown by considering the path with maximum length.
maybe the first and the second part of the question or their solutions somehow relate, I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not appear to be a homework-level task. It was first done by Chen and Saito in a [16-page paper](https://doi.org/10.1006/jctb.1994.1019), and none of the citations indicate that it could have been done more easily.

Comment: Actually it's one the questions is my weekly homework! Thanks.

Comment: Well, presumably there is a mistake in the weekly homework.